# How to search a particular Google Group and Body (versus Subject)

Tags: google-groups

I'm trying to search for a past post to the Google Group [Android Security Discussions](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/android-security-discuss). The search I used is:

```
app rating site:groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/android-security-discuss
```

I'm getting back spurious results because it appears Google's search only considers *"groups.google.com"*, and not the *"forum/#!forum/android-security-discuss"*.

There's also a way to search directly from Google Groups, but it only has a *Subject* field, and I need to search in the *Body*:

[image]

How do I search a particular Google Group and the Body of a message (versus the Subject of a message)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the Advanced Search of Google Groups use the "Has the words" or "No has the words" fields. This will look in the body and the subject.

The search operator for subject is subject:keyword.

In Google Web Search use the following

for topics (the initial post of each thread)
`site:groups.google.com/d/topic/groupname/ term1 term2` 
i.e. 
[site:groups.google.com/d/topic/android-security-discuss/ app rating](https://www.google.com.mx/search?q=site%3Agroups.google.com%2Fd%2Ftopic%2Fandroid-security-discuss%2F+app+rating)

for messages (all posts)
`site:groups.google.com/d/msg/groupname/ searchterm1 searchterm2`
i.e.
[site:groups.google.com/d/msg/android-security-discuss/ app rating](https://www.google.com.mx/search?q=site%3Agroups.google.com%2Fd%2Fmsg%2Fandroid-security-discuss%2F+app+rating)